# why this compiler error? - no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&)'

Tags: c++, gcc

This works on Visual Studio and it works on GCC 4.9.2 on one computer.

But on a different computer, I think it's the same GCC 4.9.2 compiler, but it gives me this error.

Am I missing something? What's going on?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filename;
    filename = "teststring";
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(filename);
    fout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
||=== Build: Debug in fileiotest (compiler: TDM32 GNU GCC Compiler 4.9.2 dw2) ===|
F:\Users\XXX\cpp\fileiotest\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
F:\Users\XXX\cpp\fileiotest\main.cpp|12|error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&)'|
F:\Users\XXX\cpp\fileiotest\main.cpp|12|note: candidate is:|
F:\TDM-GCC-32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2-dw2\include\c++\fstream|716|note: void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]|
F:\TDM-GCC-32\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.9.2-dw2\include\c++\fstream|716|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: You need `-std=c++11` or later.

Comment: Please don't write answers in comments, @T.C. This is a question & answer repository, not a question & comment repository.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I dunno, a filter of SO hiding everything except the comments would be reasonably useful.

Comment: @Yakk: That would make it a message board. Feel free to start up a new website with that model! But if memory serves the entire purpose of SO is to get away from it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This overload's new in C++11, which means you need to pass `-std=c++11` in the build command.

In C++03, we used to write this:

```
fout.open(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that I set that compiler flag on one computer and not on the other.

Comment: So, before c++11, how would you open a file where the file name is in a string variable?